# Ratchet websocket server not responding after some hour

Tags: websocket, ratchet

Hi i am using ratchet fas my websocket server.I run the server by using the below command.

```
nohup php path../chat-server.php > ratchet_ws.log &
```

But its terminated after some time.So i have implemented the supervisor concept given in Rachet website
http://socketo.me/docs/deploy.

It keep my chat-server.php running but its not responding after 4-5 hours.

Thanks for any help.